# Is there a REST-style API I can use to automate registration of Bots in the Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: botframework

I would like to automate registration of bots in the MS Bot Framework (https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new) but I cannot find any REST endpoint or client library to do so.

Is it possible to automate bot registration? Or does it have to be done manually via the web portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible at this time and you have to do it manually.